# Javascript: Check for same values within a class

Tags: javascript, class, input

I have multiple input-text-fields, all with the same class. Now i need to check if the user entered the same value in 2 or more of those text inputs.
Is there a way to check for that with javascript?

Comment: Hm, not with JavaScript. You could serialize the DOM and send it to your server, e.g. CGI scripts can do this.

Comment: you are supposed to have done research on the issue before asking questions on SO. This is a very simple thing, so this is not a good question. Also, @ŠimeVidas is wrong, you can do this with javascript

Comment: Well, someone has to do his homework ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like this:

```
function check() {
    var values = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; ++i) {
        var val = tests[i].value;
        if (values[val]) {
            return true;
        }
        values[val] = true;
    }
}
```

I used a hash because it is faster than `indexOf` in an array.
Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/tQJKy/1/

Comment: "same value in 2 or more", this code fails with more than two fields. ex: shouldnt "2 2 3" return `false` as all the vales are not the same.

Comment: @atomman I interpreted it as "at least two of the fields have the same value."

Comment: Fair enough interpretation. Just leaving [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U8ccE/) in case. Just some pointers to your code though: I would really like to see a `return false` at the end of your function. And even better, imho, taking the list of classname as an argument to the function. However, this is SO and code should probably not be scrutinized so much for their "prettiness".

Comment: @soktinpk This is just working fine for me. Since im kinda new to js im trying to figure out what exactly  "values[val] = true;" does in combination with the if statement. I guess "values[val]" creates a new property within values set to true? So what does the if statement checks?

Comment: @ovih the `if (values[val])` checks if the the current `val` has been seen before. If `val` has not been seen then `values[val]` will be `undefined` will is treated as `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<input class="tInput" name="1" value="a">
<input class="tInput" name="2" value="b">
<input class="tInput" name="3" value="c">
<input class="tInput" name="4" value="c">
<input class="tInput" name="5" value="a">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var list = new Array();

    $('.tInput').each(function(i, o) {
        var $o = $(o);        

        if (list.indexOf($o.val()) == -1)
            list.push($o.val());
        else
            console.log($o.val()); // Repeated 2 or more times      
    });    
});
</script>
</html>
```